# Angular 4 Deployed in Spring MVC has Images and Stylesheet problems

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc

I deployed my Angular (4) Project in the Spring MVC Project. The Java Web Project is able to work with the Angular Project however the External Stylesheets and the Images files are not being recognized.
I have placed the Css and Image Files in the **assets** folder of the Angular Project.

Note: The Angular Project is Deployed into the **webapp** folder the Spring MVC Maven Project

---

I included the external Stylesheets in the **style.css** file of the Angular Project like this

```
@import url("/assets/css/header.css");
@import url("/assets/css/footer.css");
@import url("/assets/css/content.css");
```

---

and the I used the Image files in some styles like this:

```
.check-status{
    background-image: url("/assets/images/header.png");
}
```

---

I am getting Error Messages like this:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/assets/css/footer.css net::ERR_ABORTED
GET http://localhost:8080/assets/images/header 404 ()
```

Is it related to the Angular Project Build Problem? If yes, How do I need to build the Angular Project so that I can deploy in the Spring MVC Project?
Also, What is the Best way to import the CSS and Image files in the Angular Project so that when the angular project is deployed in the Java Web Project Environment will work properly?

Comment: Angular doesn't care whether the backend is boot, MVC, nodejs, php or whatever. Spring MVC doesn't care if the frontend is angular, React, jQuery or whatever. They're independant of each other. So, find any MVC tutorial to learn how MVC works. And find any angular tutorial to know how angular works.

Comment: I am having problem in integrating the Spring MVC with the Angular 2/4. I can work on these separately however I am trying to find resources to integrate these two together.

Comment: Asking for tutorials or any other kind of external resources is off-topic. If you have a specific integration problem, then ask about that specific integration problem.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is just a SPA framework for building front end of a application. It does not depend on whichever backend language/framework you choose.

Anyhow you can look at this example, if you want to have spring MVC as a backend.

**[`SpringMVC-Angular2`](https://github.com/sajeetharan/SpringMVC-Angular2)**